# Legal to land on a beach?

Tags: faa-regulations

If you have a plane like a Cub or Scout, is it legal to land on a beach, river bank, or other similar feature or will the FAA take your certificate if you do it? I can't find any info on this anywhere but see lots of YouTube videos of people doing it.

This question is not in reference to an airplane with an emergency, I'm talking about a voluntary, intentional landing on a beach with the purpose of fishing or camping, like is done with many bush planes.

Comment: You'll probably get in trouble [if you're stupid about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3Uaqx_xVNg).

Comment: They should have some kind of horn on an airplane to get everyone everyone off the beach before it lands

Comment: @Ethan - The only reliable such horn on an aircraft in a condition such that it needs to set down in a hurry would be a compressed air horn, which is just one more piece of equipment that would have to be checked during the annual but rarely used. Other issues such as the need to shield the horn from wind blast (otherwise the back pressure would silence it) are fairly easily dealt with but can reduce the directionality and volume of the horn, and thus the ability to alert the very people you have it for in the first place.

Comment: Haha, that's good stuff.

Comment: [Copalis State Airport](https://skyvector.com/?ll=47.16357498311039,-124.17434692040173&chart=301&zoom=1&fpl=%20S16%20undefined) is literally a [beach](https://www.google.com/search?q=copalis+state+airport&&tbm=isch)

Comment: @ob318 There is no reason to put "under FAA regulations" into the title, as the question is already tagged such. Per this StackExchange Meta question it is simply not needed, even for search engine optimization.